# Check for empty fields in form

Tags: c#, wpf, constraints

Is it possible to check a form for any empty text boxes rather than having to put a check on each individual text box with an if? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. Anything is possible if you use your imagination.

Comment: You can databind the textboxes and use validation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with WPF, but you might try to get a list of the child-elements in a form, and for each, check if they are of type `Textbox`. If so, perform your validation.